# K8s TLS Secret for Postgres | GKE & Google Cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: postgresql, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm having troubles establishing a SSL connection between a web service and a remotely hosted Postgres database.  With the same cert and key files being used for the web service, I can connect to the database with tools such as pgAdmin and DataGrip.  These files were downloaded from Postgres instance in the Google Cloud Console.

**Issue:**

At the time of Spring Boot service start up, the following error occurs:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not read SSL key file /tls/tls.key
```

Where I look at the Postgres server logs, the error is recorded as

```
LOG: could not accept SSL connection: UNEXPECTED_RECORD
```

**Setup:**

Spring Boot service running on Minikube (local) and GKE connecting to a Google Cloud SQL Postgres instance.

**Actions Taken:**

I have downloaded the client cert & key.  I created a K8s TLS Secret using the downloaded client cert & key.  I also have made sure the files can be read from the volume mount by running the following command on the k8s deployment config:

```
command: ["bin/sh", "-c", "cat /tls/tls.key"]
```

Here is the datasource url which is fed in via an environment variable (DATASOURCE).

```
"jdbc:postgresql://[Database-Address]:5432/[database]?ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslcert=/tls/tls.crt&sslkey=/tls/tls.key"
```

Here is the k8s deployment yaml, any idea where i'm going wrong?

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "service.name" . }}
  labels:
    release: {{ template "release.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "chart.name" . }}
    chart-version: {{ template "chart.version" . }}
  release: {{ template "service.fullname" . }}
spec: 
  replicas: {{ $.Values.image.replicaCount }}
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "service.name" . }}
        release: {{ template "release.name" . }}
        env: {{ $.Values.environment }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ $.Values.image.pullSecretsName }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ template "service.name" . }}
          image: {{ $.Values.image.repo }}:{{ $.Values.image.tag }}
          # command: ["bin/sh", "-c", "cat /tls/tls.key"]
          imagePullPolicy: {{ $.Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: tls-cert
              mountPath: "/tls"
              readOnly: true
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: DATASOURCE_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: service
                  key: DATASOURCE_URL
            - name: DATASOURCE_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: service
                  key: DATASOURCE_USER
            - name: DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: service
                  key: DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
      volumes:
        - name: tls-cert
          projected:
            sources:
              - secret:
                  name: postgres-tls
                  items:
                    - key: tls.crt
                      path: tls.crt
                    - key: tls.key
                      path: tls.key
```

Comment: Is the container running as root or as a different account, if different account please ensure that account has read permissions on /tls/tls.key

Comment: @NitinMidha, I have not configured any permissions explicitly.  Do you have a link to a reference where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: As per guidelines it is not recommended to run container as root. So many Docker Images take steps to use a non root account. I had done that in one of the NGINX image and i have to assign explicit permissions in my Dockerfile. So please check base image your are using and see if they are using a non root account. Check below link.

Comment: https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b

Comment: @NitinMidha, thank you for this.  Here is my docker file

    FROM openjdk:8
    EXPOSE 80
    ADD /target/service.jar service.jar
    ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar service.jar

Comment: @NitinMidha, I tried running everything at root, just to make sure I can access the file.  I still get the error, although when I kubectl exe into the container, I can access and read the cert and key.  I have tried the key in different ways, making it a .pk8 and .key.  I don't think it is access privileges because when I run the command to cat the file, it can be accessed and it appears in the log output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out, I was asking the wrong question!

Google Cloud SQL has a proxy component for the Postgres database.  Therefore, trying to connect the traditional way (the problem I was trying to solve) has been resolved by implementing proxy.  Instead of dealing with whitelisting IPs, SSL certs, and such, you just spin up the proxy, point it at a GCP credential file, then updated your database uri to access via localhost.

To set up the proxy, you can find directions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine).  There is a good example of a k8s deployment file [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/postgres_deployment.yaml).

One situation I did come across was the GCP service account.  Make sure to add Cloud SQL Client AND Cloud SQL Editor roles.  I only added the Cloud SQL Client to start with and kept getting the 403 error.